# Convert datetime from excel format into the sql format

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading values from Excel and inserting read rows to SQL, but I'm facing an issue with date columns.

From Excel I'm reading the dates as `23-08-2011 01:33:01`, but in the database the values are stored as `2011-08-22 10:21:18.000`.

Is there a way I can convert in C# (not in T-SQL) the date I'm reading to a `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00:000` format? I want to convert `23-08-2011 01:33:01` to `2011-08-23 00:00:00:000`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Parse Excel string into `DateTime` object using `DateTime.ParseExact`
2. Format `DateTime` object into SQL format using `String.Format` and the appropriate format string.

See these two resources for guide how to create a DateTime format string:

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
DateTime excel = DateTime.ParseExact("23-08-2011 01:33:01", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
String sqlString = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:ffff}", excel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method from `DateTime`

```
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("23-08-2011 01:33:01", 
    "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Depending on how you're inserting your records, you should be able to use your DateTime object, otherwise you can store it as a string:

```
string sqlDate = parsedDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:fff");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string dateString = "23-08-2011 01:33:01";            
string format = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";            
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string again = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00:000");
```